# Visual Studio python reading files relative paths

Tags: python, visual-studio, path

I opened a python project folder in visual studio and run `getter.py` which contains following code:

```
getter.py
with open('instruments.txt', 'r') as f:
    instrument_list = f.read().splitlines()
```

My folder tree is as follows:

```
proj
    -downloaders
        --getter.py
    instruments.txt
    signals.py
```

As you see above `getter.py` is located in `donwloaders` folder. Why visual studio run the above script without `FileNotFoundError`? Please, note that, when I move `instructions.txt` to `downloaders` folder, it throws `FileNotFoundError`. Should I change something in settings?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are placing your txt file in your python script directory, and not your python project directory.

```
proj
    -downloaders
        --getter.py
        --instruments.txt
    signals.py
```